# Differenza tra “voce” e “vocina”

Tags: difference, vocabulary, nouns

Cerco la differenza tra *voce* e *vocina*. Il mio traduttore mi dice "voice" per entrambi.

"Da dove viene questa vocina?"
"...dalla voce che esce..."

Comment: "Vocina" è un diminutivo di "voce": http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/voce.shtml.

Answer (score 2):

*Voce* è la corretta traduzione della *voice* inglese. *Vocina* è il suo diminutivo e viene spesso usata per indicare la *voce* di un bambino o una *voce* molto lieve e poco rumorosa.

Comment: Potrebbe anche essere usata per dileggio, ma occorre una frase più lunga per stabilire questo tipo di utilizzo.